# Dedekind domain necessary for equivalence of flatness and torsion-free

Tags: commutative-algebra, noetherian, dedekind-domain

It is well-known that for finitely generated modules over a Dedekind domain, flatness and torsion-free are equivalent. Is this true for general Noetherian rings? If not, where is the dimension one property used?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In fact, the property has nothing to do with dimension (it is actually a homological property), but with special properties of ideals. If $R$ is a domain, then your property is equivalent with $R$ [Prüfer domain](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pr%C3%BCfer_domain), and noetherian Prüfer domains are Dedekind.

Comment: I disagree with your first sentence. As you say: Prufer + Noetherian implies 1 dimensional!!!  It is good to keep in mind that homological dimension and Krull dimension tend to agree in nice settings.